# Remove objects from a List if the objects have duplicate property

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a List of objects. All of the objects contain a NAME property. There are several objects that have the same NAME property.

```
  const arr = [
    {name: "x", place: "a",  age: "13" },
    {name: "x", place: "b", age: "14" },
    {name: "y", place: "c",  age: "15" },
    {name: "d", place: "d", age: "16" }
]
```

How can I trim the List (or make a new List) where there is only one object per NAME property? Any other duplicates should be removed of the List

I should get a result like this

```
    const arr = [
    {name: "x", place: "a",  age: "13" },
    {name: "y", place: "c",  age: "15" },
    {name: "d", place: "d", age: "16" }
]
```

or

```
    const arr = [
    {name: "x", place: "b", age: "14" },
    {name: "y", place: "c",  age: "15" },
    {name: "d", place: "d", age: "16" }
]
```

can i do it with Lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash's [`uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) function is exactly what you need:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const result = _.uniqBy(arr, 'name');
```